# How to call an api in django signals

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Can someone share a code about how to call an api in django signals.Here is some code that i have done:

```
@receiver(pre_delete, sender=Product)
def pre_delete_profile(sender, **kwargs):
    print("You are about to delete something!")
    *** some API call***
```

Comment: whenever Product object will be delete signal will be called

Comment: What do you want to for example? In your code, the function is named `pre_delete_profile` but it is called by `pre_delete` of the Product model...

Comment: i dont need it i already have done it all i want is that I need to call an API inside signals

Comment: updated it please see what i want

Comment: use requests, https://pypi.org/project/requests/

Comment: import requests,   r = requests.post('your_api_url', data={'key': 'value'})

Comment: Note that django singnals are synchronized, means the your request will wait until the singnal to complete. If its not desired thing about use some task queue  like celery or django-rq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just stick to [requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/):

```py
# handlers.py
import requests

@receiver(pre_delete, sender=Product)
def pre_delete_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    print("You are about to delete something!")
    data = {'id': instance.pk}
    url = 'https://www.google.com/'
    r = requests.post(url=url, data=data)
```